# After using QFileDialog program crashes after few seconds

Tags: c++, qt, crash, qfiledialog

I am making app to increase productivity in our company. It reads the whole .csv file and puts its contents to a table in .pdf format. I am using QT as GUI library and PoDoFo as .pdf library.

The thing is, after I let user select .csv file to get data from and path to save generated .pdf, the program crashes in two minutes or so. It varies from case to case. I was able to "track" the issue down to the QFileDialog.

It doesn't matter if I created it on the stack, or dynamically still the same thing happens. From the moment you press "Choose" in the GUI, which opens up file dialog, program will crash in something around a two minutes giving this in Visual Studio Community 2017

[image]

I was able to create minimalistic code, to reproduce the error. I am using Windows 7 Pro, Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017, compiling 32-bit debug

.h,.cpp,.ui files: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/cf057p4lnumesol/AAD39zDJnrxGChXAuE7y27Kra?dl=0

Any help would be appreciated, I've spent 5 days of my free time trying to figure this out. Thanks

EDIT: I understand that the "Frame not in module" means that visual studio doesn't have debugging symbols for the part of code where crash occurred, since I did not built qt myself, that makes sense.

EDIT2: I am using QT Visual Studio Tools addon version 2.3.2
Qt version is 5.12.2

EDIT3: Crashes only occurs when compiling for 32-bit arch.

EDIT4: Crash is happening only if using native file dialog. If option `QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog` is set, then no crash occurrs.

Comment: Could need more info on the Qt version and how you moc/build under visual (do you do it yourself or do you use visual add-on?). I tried your sample with Qt5.10 with QtCreator and MinGW 32-bits compiler and it worked just fine even after 10 mins

Comment: I'll add it right away, although your input is incredibly helpful as well.

Comment: Does it crash if you open the dialog put do not close it? Is your code really minimalistic ? For instance, if you remove `MainWindow::setupLoadDialog()`? Does it still crash ?

Comment: Yes, you are right, it could be minimized more :D...I removed the setup and updated qt to 5.12.2, still the same thing happens

Comment: By any chance, are you using the same compiler for both platform? (x86 and x64)

Comment: Well, I've never done anything compiler related inside of Visual Studio so I believe cl.exe is being called.

Comment: If you are using the Visual Studio plugin you must have set some Qt option at some point like this https://puu.sh/DbIMz/fcbe8cb014.png. If you plan on build for x86 et x64 you need to create 2 (with msvc 32-bits and 64-bits) and set each for each project individually.

Comment: If you meant this "setting" then yes, I have both msvc2017 and msvc2017_64, it would not compile otherwise. This is runtime error not compile time

Comment: When you right click you project (in x86 configuration) and go to "Qt project settings" do you have to correct version of your configuration set? https://puu.sh/DbISs/9ca55e281f.png Sometimes the Add-on messes up and don't change accordingly between 32 and 64bits.

Comment: Yes, I have only one version and the architecture is x86, so I'm good there. However I added EDIT4, which makes me think there is some service, or background process doing something to explorers. I've seen some post about git screwing things up.

Comment: I installed Qt5.12 and tried again on my visual 2017 (with add-on) and it still works just fine in x86 but I'm on windows 10 (and I also have git)

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort. Now I found out it crashes only in debug mode. So I could live with that, if it does not affect people using it.

Comment: An attitude a bit dangerous. Just because it *apparently* doesn't occur doesn't mean that it *cannot* occur, and if a user does some things differently than you do, the problem might re-appear – just be aware of, you can still decide that the risk is 'sufficiently small'...

Comment: I reported it as Qt bug, so they'll look into it I believe. Already got some responses. However, I even tried to deploy the debug binary and it did not crash. So it has to be something with visual studio debugger or something

Comment: IIRC, you can download the debug symbols separately for Windows. I don't have a Windows machine at hand but do you have the same result if you use the [getOpenFileName static method](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#getOpenFileName) ?

Comment: Yes I do, it is a bug 100% and I have .pdbs but I still get the window saying not in module

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is related, but I had an issue where if I gave a path to the FileDialog it would grind away for a few seconds because it was somehow interpreting it as a network path. To fix this I gave it a path that had a prefix of `"file://"`. To accomplish this I did this:

```
QUrl().fromLocalFile(cell_info->progDir()).toString()
```

The original path came from `cell_info->progDir()`. Somehow that path was a regular windows specific path. Once I wrapped it in the from LocalFile call it produced what I needed for all platforms I was using it with.

Again, I have no idea if this is related to your issue, but it sounds fishy like it is grinding away in the background on something. If this is not related feel free to ignore.